# Username remain when login failed in aspnet identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-identity

I have login method when user enter wrong details it gives empty login page as previous.

Here the Login method

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);

            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;

            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.Status == true && user.ConfirmedEmail == true)
                {

                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                    {
                        if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "HEC_Admin"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("U_Index", "HEC");
                        }
                        //role Admin go to Admin page
                        if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "HEI_User"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("StudentIndex", "HEI");
                        }



                    }

                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }


                }
                else if (user.ConfirmedEmail == true && user.Status == false)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The account is currently Inactive. Please contact the Administrator");
                    return View(model);
                }

                else if (user.ConfirmedEmail == false)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please click on the link provided in the confirmation email, to activate your account");
                    return View(model);
                }

                else {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The account is currently Inactive. Please contact the Administrator");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The Username or Password is invalid.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        else if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserName)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password)))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please enter the Username and Password.");
            return View(model);
        }

        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserName))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please enter the Username.");

        }

        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please enter the Password.");
            return View(model);
        }


        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

here the view

```
    <div class="form-box" id="login-box">



    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



  <div class="body bg-gray">
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <input type="text" value="" name="UserName"  id="validateHecUser_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" >

    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="validateHecUser_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" >   

    </div>


  </div>


    }
</div>
```

I want to remain the username when user login failed , how to keep username in aspnet identity membership provider

Comment: Now that you are sending model back from controller, how you are going to receive it in view?? I don't find any model in your view!!

Comment: Get rid of all those conditional statements and use the strongly typed helpers - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)` etc and add validation attributes to your model properties so you get client and server side validation

Answer (score 1):

Assign values of your inputs by Model properties, like this,

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  <input type="text" value="@Model.UserName" name="UserName"  id="validateHecUser_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" >
</div>

<div class="form-group"> 
  <input type="password" value="@Model.Password" name="password" id="validateHecUser_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" >
</div>
```

But best to use Html Helpers to render input controls, like:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.TextboxFor(model => model.UserName)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Password)
</div>
```

**Note:** Your View must be strongly typed.

Hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: thanks for the answer but when I use your 1st option it gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

error

Comment: For that you need to pass the model (by initializing 'UserName' and 'Passwor' to empty string) to View in [httpget] action-method also. But using second option would be the great choice.